# Can't make Puma run with Nginx reverse proxy in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, nginx, puma

I'm trying to make my Rails app with Puma run with Nginx.

I use `rails s` and `localhost:3000` work just fine.

But when I go to http://rails_host/, it returns

```
The server at rails_host can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address
```

From my nginx.conf

```
http {
include rails.conf;
....
}
```

Here's my `rails.conf` file config

```
upstream rails_test {  
server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name rails_host;

location /{  
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://rails_test;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

And I just don't know if can I run multi rails app (right now only 1 app a time at port 3000), is there any way to run multi rails app with only subdomain, like `rails_host/rails_app_1` and `rails_host/rails_app_2` ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DNS lookup failed for '**rails_test**', kind-of a simple thing ain't it?

Comment: ok, first - yes , I forgot to set `127.0.0.1 rails_test' in windows hosts. And secondly, my rails app run with ssl and somehow it block nginx reverse proxy. Thanks for advice.

Comment: If it blocks then either change the app to use non-blocking code or add more upstreams to spread the workload.

Answer (score 0):

by default rails app use  ssl in production mode.  Your app is running in production mode. Disable force_ssl in environtments/production.rb to false and it will work